# Pushing an Object on to an Object

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I'm having issues pushing an object onto an object. I've succefully managed to push an array onto the object, but I fail at the former.

This is what I have

```
var lapList = [1,2,3,4];
var users = [{sets: [{
                        reps: []
                        }]
                     },
                     {sets: [{
                        reps: []
                        }]
                     }];

var activeUser = users[0];
var activeSet = activeUser.sets[activeUser.sets.length-1];

activeSet.reps.push({laps: lapList});
console.log('good');
console.log(users);

activeSet.push({reps: [{laps: lapList}]});
console.log('also good');
console.log(users);
```

I get the first 'good' in the console, and I can see that the array got added successfully to the user. However, on the second test, in which I'm trying to add a new reps section, it fails, and I get a TypeError: undefined is not a function.

Any thoughts?

Comment: What does that even mean? Objects are not arrays, and have no concept of pushing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your structure is not defined properly:

users looks like:

```
[
  {sets: [{reps: []}]},
  {sets: [{reps: []}]}
];
```

This is an array with two objects as values

activeUser is the first object in the array and looks like:

```
{sets: [{reps: []}]}
```

activeSet is just reps, an array

Your first call:

```
activeSet.reps.push({laps: lapList});
```

This will work fine,

Your second call:

```
activeSet.push({reps: [{laps: lapList}]});
```

This is meaningless because activeSet is reps is an object

You could push that to activeUser.sets, which is probably what you really intended

```
activeUser.sets.push({reps: [{laps: lapList}]});
```

Comment: Great! I think this is close to what I want. One more question - what if I wanted to add a whole new set? I can't seem to do activeUser.push({sets: [{reps: [{laps: lapList}]}]}); Here is a fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/bL9Lfyyy/

Comment: Look again at the structures I just showed you.  ActiveUser is an object, users is your array

Comment: Got it - I was just confused and trying to do something one level too high. This was the answer I needed

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, JS objects don't have a `push` method.

You may want to do something like this:

`activeSet.reps.push({laps: lapList});`

or maybe

`activeSet.reps = [{laps: lapList}];`

I'm not exactly sure what you're modeling with this data structure, but those are the types of things you should be able to do with an object.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is add another whole new reps section. Both the solutions provided replace the reps section (I'm using the first one in demonstration code I listed above).

Comment: Essentially, I'm getting new data from a service, and I need to update the users array. When its a question of adding a new lap, it works as laps is just an array. However, there are cases where I need to create a reps 'sub-object' to handle different data, and that is where I'm stuck

Comment: there might be a better way to organize the data.  Can you think of other ways to structure it?

Comment: I'm honestly stuck. I essentially need a tree, where each user has a bunch of sets, which are filled with a bunch of reps, which are then filled with laps.

Comment: Describe the use case more.  Does each set have reps?  Does each rep have laps?  From what I know of exercising (which I don't is relevant) it seems like users would have sets and laps.  And then sets would have reps.

Comment: You're correct - each set is made up of 1+ reps, and each rep is made of 1+ lap. The lap array has a series of metrics for that lap - lap time, steps, distance, etc

Answer (score 0):

`activeSet` is an object. `activeSet.reps` is an array. [push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) is an array method.

push the new object to the array

```
activeUser.sets.push({reps:{laps: lapList}});
```

Answer (score 0):

Objects don't have a push method, they do have similarities in how you can loop over them though which can cause confusion sometimes. When you extend an object with a new property, it's just that and you can declare the property right on the object. Something like this works

```
//objects value is {prop1: "value1"}
var obj = {prop1: "value1"}

//objects value is now {prop1: "value1", prop2: "value2"}
obj.prop2 = "value2"
```

I get the feeling you might be using the wrong structure here though for what you're trying to accomplish. If you post an example of the final data structure you're expecting we can better help you.

Answer (score 0):

When putting this code through Firefox's console, I get a similar error to yours: `TypeError: activeSet.push is not a function`. Ah! There's the problem! The `Object` object has no such thing as a `.push()` method. You might have been in Array-laser-focus mode when you did this one ;). The concept of an Array's `.push()` method is to add a name-nonspecific value to the array. This is not one of the Object's methods because each value of any given object has to have a (meaningful) name; putting a non-named value into an object, well, confuses the poor thing. Instead, try:

```
activeSet.reps = [{laps: lapList}];
```

And, when I put this through the console again...

```
"good"
Array [ Object, Object ]
"also good"
Array [ Object, Object ]
```

Voila! Hope it helps!